# Error in Python while doing text preprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have written a couple of functions to work on text documents and convert them into bag of words. Before that I am cleaning the text by removing the stop words, tokenization etc and storing the cleaned text docs as a list which I intend to pass as an argument to another function which would create bag of words features from it.

Here is the functions:

```
def cleaningDocs(doc,stem):  # 'S' for Stemming, 'L' for Lemmatization
    """This function cleans each doc string by doing the following: 
    i)   Removing punctuation and other non alphabetical characters
    ii)  Convert to Lower case and split string into words (tokenization)
    ii)  Removes stop words (most frequent words)
    iii) Doing Stemming and Lemmatization
    """

    # Removing punctuations and other non alphabetic characters
    import re
    alphabets_only=re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]'," ",doc)

    # Converting to lower case and splitting the words(tokenization)
    words_lower=alphabets_only.lower().split()

    # Removing stop words (Words like 'a', 'an', 'is','the' which doesn't contribute anything
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    useful_words = [w for w in words_lower if not w in set(stopwords.words("english"))] 

    # Doing Stemming or Lemmatization (Normalising the text)
    from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer, WordNetLemmatizer
    if (stem=='S'):  # Choosing between Stemming ('S') and Lemmatization ('L')
        stemmer=PorterStemmer()
        final_words=[stemmer.stem(x) for x in useful_words]
    else: 
        lemma=WordNetLemmatizer()
        final_words=[lemma.lemmatize(x) for x in useful_words]

    return(str(" ".join(final_words)))
```

Now here is a list of document strings .This is a pandas Series object.

```
type(docs)
Out[53]:
pandas.core.series.Series
```

Each element within this document is a string. Basically each element is a text document and I want to pre-process each text document(get rid of stop words, lemmatization etc) and saving that as a new processed list.

```
type(docs[0])
Out[55]:
str
```

Ideally I want to do something like this:

```
doc=[]
for x in docs:
    doc.append(cleaningDocs(x,"L"))
```

So that for each string document within docs series we get rid of it with stop words and other things and save it back to a list of documents.

The above code is giving me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-61345bb4d581> in <module>()
      1 doc=[]
      2 for x in docs:
----> 3     doc.append(cleaningDocs(x,"L"))
      4 

<ipython-input-42-6e1c58274c3d> in cleaningDocs(doc, stem)
     13     # Removing punctuations and other non alphabetic characters
     14     import re
---> 15     alphabets_only=re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]'," ",doc)
     16 
     17     # Converting to lower case and splitting the words(tokenization)

/Users/mtripathi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/re.pyc in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    153     a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
    154     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 155     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    156 
    157 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Whereas if I de-bug it by just passing the first element of docs (first document)  by adding break to above for loop; it works totally fine.

```
doc=[]
for x in docs:
    doc.append(cleaningDocs(x,"L"))
    break

doc
```

if you see the function does as required by removing the stop words from the original document and lemmatization it and then saving it back to a new processed list of documents. But it is working if I am sending only one document at a time. While sending all documents in a for loop it is throwing an error why would that be?.

EDIT:

Ok I just checked the type of each element in docs and see there is some issue happening that there is some elements getting casted as float there. See below:

```
for x in docs: 
    print(type(x))
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'float'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
```

So couple of things:

1) I want to see those elements which are float in this doc. 
2). Second if I want to convert all the elements to string I guess we can do .astype()?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pass a list `doc` into `re.sub()`, when you should only be passing a string.

Comment: Well I am passing a string only if you see?.docs is a series and elements of docs are string as Shown above. When I do for x in docs, i would get a string (text document) and that is passed. That is why it is working if I just check it for one doc.

Comment: Please check edit. There is some values as float I found are there in the docs

Comment: Investigate or pass if isinstance(x, str) is False.

Comment: Just saw. I have some missing values which were reported as nan and casted as float.

Answer (score 0):

So there are two main ideas here: [Boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [function application](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#function-application)

Boolean indexing allows you to use a true/false array to select a subset of a Series, and function application applies a single function to every item in a Series.

First, apply `isinstance` to determine which elements are floats, then slice your series to get the elements back.

Then just apply `str` and you're good.

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.Series(["Hey", "I'm", 1.0, "or", 2.0, "floats"])
# Find floats 
floats = test[test.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, float))]
# Make all strings
test_as_strings = test.apply(str)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.